# LINQ how to concatenate 2 db columns to display in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to concatenate `product_name` with `product_prize_kg` by using LINQ so I can display it as one field in a dropdownlist. When I try to do this I get the following error.

> *value of type 'system.collections.generic.list(of anonymous type )'
>   cannot be converted to ...*

My code is like this:

```
Public Function selectAll() As List(Of tblProduct)
    Dim result = From product In dc.tblProducts
                 Select New With
                 {
                    Key .productID = product.pk_product_id,
                    Key .productNameKg = Convert.ToString(product.product_name) & " " & Convert.ToString(product.product_price_kg)
                 }

    Return result.ToList()
End Function
```

This is the dropdownlist that I want to fill.

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataTextField="productNameKg" 
        DataValueField="productID">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Thanks

Grtz Simke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function selectAll() As List(Of Product)
    Dim result = From product In tblProducts
                 Select New Product With
             {
                .ProductId = product.pk_product_id,
                .ProductNameKg = Convert.ToString(product.product_name) & " " & Convert.ToString(product.product_price_kg)
             }


    Return result.ToList()
End Function



Public Class Product

    Property ProductId As String

    Property ProductNameKg As String

End Class
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I get an error at the first bracket ( { ) : Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.' thanks for helping

Comment: If I remove the Key in front of .productID the error disappears, but I get a new error: 'productID' is not a member of 'tblProduct' but what I'm trying to do is creating my own members so I can display 2 fields in a dropdownlist. I can display product_name in my dropdownlist but not product_name + product_prize_kg.

Comment: You are trying to return it as a List(of tblProduct) but you are creating an anonymous type with two properties (productID and productNameKg). If you wish to return the List you need to create the class with the two properties. If you weren't returning it as the value of a function (ie. having the binding call and the Linq query in the same method) then it would work.

Comment: I have updated the answer for you again! Sorry I am converting C# to VB.NET on-the-fly